# Process web API callback's response after window.location.href redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, openid

I have a Web Api which handles OpenId sign in such way:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = "")
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await GetAuthUser();
            string userId = user?.Id;

            var properties = _externalSignInService.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, Url.Action("ExternalCallback", "Account", new { returnUrl, userId }));

            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }
```

This is called from Angular app with JS redirect function (it is hardcoded, because I am trying to make it works firstly).

```
     public loginExternal() {
        window.location.href = `https://localhost:5001/v1/account/ExternalLogin?provider=Steam&returnUrl=${window.location.href}`;
      }
```

After Steam login success, it makes to callback method specified there  `Url.Action(...)`

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Steam", Name = "ExternalCallback")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResponseDto>> ExternalCallback(string error = null, string returnUrl = "", string userId = null)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl + "/unauthorized");
            }

            ...sign in duties...

            return ProduceLoginResponse(signInResult);
        }
```

```
private ActionResult<LoginResponseDto> ProduceLoginResponse((AppSignInResult result, SignInData data) loginResults)
        {
            var (result, data) = loginResults;

            return result switch
            {
                AppSignInResult.Success => Ok(new LoginResponseDto()
                {
                    AccessToken = data.Token.AccessToken,
                    TokenType = data.Token.TokenType,
                    ExpiresIn = data.Token.GetRemainingLifetimeSeconds(),
                    Username = data.Username,
                    Email = data.Email,
                    IsExternalLogin = data.IsExternalLogin,
                    ExternalAuthenticationProvider = data.ExternalAuthenticationProvider
                }),
                _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException($"Unknown sign-in result '{result}'.")
            };
        }
```

[image]

So in my Angular app I need to process this data (save JWT token in storage, etc..). How to do it keeping in mind that I used `window.location.href` redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out with saving user sign in data in `HttpContext.Session` storage and changing return approach from `return ProduceLoginResponse(signInResult);` to `return Redirect(returnHost + "/sign-in");` and after redirect, in angular SignIn component inside `ngOnInit` method I am calling another endpoint to get my sign in data from `HttpContext.Session` storage.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("sign-in")]
        public ActionResult<object> ProvideSignInDataFromSession()
        {
            var sessionData = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SignInDataKey);

            if (sessionData != null)
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInData>(sessionData);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    user = data.Username,
                    access_token = data.Token.AccessToken,
                    token_type = data.Token.TokenType,
                    expires_in = data.Token.GetRemainingLifetimeSeconds(),
                });
            }

            return Redirect(CORS.CORS.returnOrigin + "/unauthorized");
        }
```